# List all transactions within specified timeframe with Amazon Pay API

Tags: amazon-pay

I have searched the documentation of the Amazon Pay API, however couldn't find a function that would allow retrieving all transactions within a specified time frame. PayPal, however, does provide such a function with it's API. This is why I am wondering Amazon does not - any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact question, and after searching without success for the answer or relevant documentation, I opened a support ticket with Amazon MWS.

Amazon MWS support directed me to the [Programmatic Access to
Amazon Payments Reports document](https://amazonpayments.s3.amazonaws.com/documents/Programmatic%20Access%20to%20Amazon%20Payments%20Reports.pdf) (pdf).  It appears to describe the API for getting settlement and transaction reports.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. There is another document that apparently helps with this issue: http://amazonpayments.s3.amazonaws.com/documents/Settlement_Report_Documentation_DE.pdf?ld=NSGoogle